# VLC plugin for android browser

Tags: android, video, browser, video-streaming, vlc

i found VLC for Android Beta (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&hl=sk) which enables to play videos in VLC player on Android. But I need VLC plugin for browser on Android (for default browser or for chrome or any other browser). Is it possible ? Can you suggest mi anything ? When I installed VLC for Android Beta it not contains web plugin...

btw, I am using android 4.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no VLC web plugin for Android and it's highly questionable (if not impossible) if it's actually even technically feasible to develop such a thing.
Just open your links in the VLC for Android, e.g. by using the vlc:// protocol handler which will be introduced by the next update.

Comment: Could you link to documentation on this alleged feature?